# Composite pattern with visitor, what really goes in visitor and how?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, composite, visitor-pattern

Composite pattern is often used with visitor. I am trying to figure out what exactly goes into composite and what in visitor. For example if one of the composite has unique property/attribute, will it still be stored in it and visitor will only dig it out or visitor will keep it?

I have written a quick demo to illustrate the problem (note: I have minimized code).

```
using namespace std;

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual string visit(class Manager * manager) = 0;
    virtual string visit(class SalesPerson * salesPerson) = 0;

};


class Employee
{
public:
    virtual void add(Employee * employee) = 0;
    virtual void remove(Employee * employee) = 0;
    virtual string name() = 0;
    virtual string department() = 0;
    virtual int salary() = 0;

    virtual void awardBonus(int amount) = 0;

    virtual void accept(Visitor * v) = 0;

protected:
    string m_name;
    string m_dept;
    int m_salary;

};



class Manager : public Employee
{
protected:
    QList <Employee *> subordinates;

    virtual void add(Employee * employee)
    {
        subordinates.append( employee );
    }
    virtual void remove(Employee * employee) {};
    virtual string name() { return m_name; };
    virtual string department() { return m_dept; };
    virtual int salary() { return m_salary; };

    virtual void awardBonus(int amount) {};

    void accept(Visitor *v)
    {
        v->visit(this);
    }

};

class SalesPerson: public Employee
{
public:
    float commision; // sales employee gets commision
    string territory;

    SalesPerson(): territory("Unknown") {};

    void accept(Visitor *v)
    {
        v->visit(this);
    }

    virtual void add(Employee * employee) {};
    virtual void remove(Employee * employee) {};
    virtual string name() { return m_name; };
    virtual string department() { return m_dept; };
    virtual int salary() { return m_salary; };

    virtual void awardBonus(int amount) {};

};



class AwardStockOptionsVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    int shares;

    string visit(Manager *manager)
    {
        shares = 200;

    }

    string visit(SalesPerson *salesPerson)
    {
        shares = 100;
    }

};

class GetTerritoryVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    string territory;
    string visit(Manager *manager)
    {
        return "";
    }

    string visit(SalesPerson *salesPerson)
    {
        territory = salesPerson->territory;
        return salesPerson->territory;
    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Employee * manager = new Manager;

    Employee * salesPerson = new SalesPerson;

    GetTerritoryVisitor * getTerritory = new GetTerritoryVisitor;
    salesPerson->accept( getTerritory );

    cout << "Sales territory is " << getTerritory->territory  << endl;

    manager->add( salesPerson );
}
```

In this example, an employee can have a lot of attributes, some of them differ from one another depending on what kind of employee it is.

For example SalesPerson has a territory attribute which is not applicable to other employees, does the composite still store it and visitor only retrieves its value? In that case will we need two visitors to `setValue()` and `getValue()` if I need these operations? The 2nd paradigm is should the visitor instead store this attribute, in essence add this property which would otherwise not exist in employee?

How about stock options property which is lets assume is given only to 5% employees. Should this be stored in composite and extended by visitor?

One of my concern is employee composite can have many additional attributes which could also mean differences widening up in derived class. Is it okay if composite has relatively large attributes that doesn't actually apply to all sub classes? Should we add property via visitor or only use visitor to provide interface to the specific additional properties that a unique subclass may have?

Comment: From your example it is not clear how do you use the Composite. Why the `getTerritory` should be in the visitor? Why don't just use `salesPerson->getTerritory()`?

Comment: @BorisSerebrov That's actually what my question is. If I do that, I will have to add `getTerritory()` method to the base `Employee` class which will obviously be only applicable to `SalesPerson` type. Is that the right way since it only applies to one type of employee? Should I move it to visitor? That's the question.

Comment: the real use case is still missing. For sure, you should put the `getTerritory()` into the `SalesPerson`. What is not really clear is if your choice of composite + visitor is good. And you don't describe how exactly you use the composite in your example, you just pass visitor to individual objects. And if you pass the visitor through the `Composite` structure, how are you going to use the value visitor returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both design patterns are complementary, their intent is different:

- The [**composite**](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) is a structural pattern.  The intent is to represent hierarchies and tread individual objects and composition of objects uniformly.
- The [**visitor**](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) is a behavioural pattern.  The intent is to represent an operation to be performed on the elements of an objective structure.

According to this principle, the visitor is not there to store persistent data. So, yes, any attributes that might be specific to a category of employees shall remain in the composite.

The fact that you have large sets of attributes (wheteher specific to one employee derivate or common to all) doesn't change the principles.  The visitor pattern is intended to cope with different kind of elements in the composite, with the use of different visitinging member functions (one for each different class).

The only inconvenience, is when you add new classes to your composite structure, you'd need to revise your visitors accordingly.

You would put some values in the visitor, only temporarily, to perform an operation.  For example:

- you could have a vistor to totalize the number of people below a manager, and their total salary
- or you could have a total number of shares for a visitor which impelemnts an algorithm to hierarchically distribute these shares on the employee.  At the end of the distribution, the shares left in the visitor would be 0, so that you'd need some shareholder counter in the composite.

**Implementation questions:**

Your implementation of the visitor pattern is incomplete. You have no visiting logic that goes through composite structure.

Looking at the way you intend to use your visitor, I wonder if you are not looking for adding attributes/functions to objects, instead of browsing through them.

I suggest you have a look at the [**decorator pattern**](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html), which is better suited to this kind of usage: it's a structural pattern, that extends an existing family of classes.

Comment: Thanks, you have addressed exactly the questions that were in mind. So the attributes remains with composite, makes sense. But since every composite operation (loosely speaking)  translate into a derived class of visitor, does it mean I will have to derive two visitor classes just to set attributes and read them back(should I need to set/read)?

Comment: exactly the answer i would have written +1

Comment: No you don't have to make a visitor for any operations on your composite objects unless it is a complex set/get. I mean if your intent is to get/set data through an hardware protocol, the business logic could be complicated and different for any kind of composite objects. So there Visitor could fit very well. For a typical setter/getter it would be overkill

Comment: @floppy12 so for a typical getter/setter, just an interface function in the base class of composite will do and obviously it will only be implemented manfully in that particularly derived class?

Comment: The getter/setter should only be present in the derived class where they make sense (where the member variable is present), no need to make them virtual in the base composite class. However, if your intent is still to "get some related data" (by calling all the individual related getter methods) from your full hierarchy of objects then you could think your Visitor as a data collector which will crawl the hierarchy, storing/converting each individual data and returning the full thing as a collection for instance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that returning something from the `Visitor`'s `visit` method will not really work:

```
class GetTerritoryVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    string territory;
    string visit(Manager *manager)
    {
        return ""; // who will use this?
    }

    string visit(SalesPerson *salesPerson)
    {
        territory = salesPerson->territory; // this will be overwritten
        return salesPerson->territory; // and who will use this?
    }

};
```

The way `Visitor` + `Composite` works is this (pseudo-code):

```
class Composite {

     function accept(Visitor visitor) {
         foreach (element in this->getElements()) {
             element->accept(visitor);
         }
         this->accept(visitor);
     }
 }

 Visitor visitor = new GetTerritoryVisitor();
 composite->accept(visitor);
```

Keep in mind that in general case the `visitor` object will visit many objects. So there is no way to "capture" the value returned from its `visit` method.

Also if you save the individual result in the property, like you do in `GetTerritoryVisitor`, it will not work as well, because it will be overwritten by each `SalesPerson` you visit.

Usually `Visitor` does something with the object or accumulates some information.

So I could imagine the visitor which creates a list of territories of sales mans:

```
class GetTerritoryVisitor : public Visitor {
    list territories;

    string visit(SalesPerson *salesPerson) {
        this->territories->add(salesPerson->territory);
    }

    list getTerritories() {
        return this->territories;
    }

};

Visitor visitor = new GetTerritoryVisitor();
composite->accept(visitor);
// now we have a list of territories of all sales mans
// and can use it for something
allTerritories = visitor->getTerritories();
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant with the implementation of the visitor pattern being incomplete. Useful contribution to the understanding of visitors: +1

Comment: Thanks for the nice insight, the return value is something I am trying to understand. Most examples out there don't return values from visitor but instead print that value inside the visitor (derived). But I was like if it's gonna calculate something new, I will probably want to show it in UI outside the visitor somewhere. I will dig in this more but It seems like based on your answer, `visitor` shouldn't be used as getters/setters. +1 from me.